# Is it OK to say 'become to do'?

Tags: expressions

I just used an expression like this by accident;

> I'll definitely try it when I become not to worry about that.

I don't know why I thought this expression is OK, but I've got curious how frequently people use this 'become to (verb)' form. I goggled it but I hadn't found any usage, so I think it might be an ill-formed English.

Comment: This is sentence is not grammatical or understandable. Can you explain what you want to say, by for example describing a situation when you might want to say it?

Comment: @JavaLatte The OP clearly means "to start/stop doing something" and is probably confused because the word that translates "become" into his language probably also means starting and stopping doing something (transition from one state (or _action_) to another).

Comment: The purpose of ELL is not just to answer individual people's questions, but to create a repository of questions and answers that a much larger group of people can benefit from. This only works is the question is clear and the answers are all responses to the same understanding of he question. I am not saying that your interpretation of the word **become** is not correct, but in my opinion it is far from obvious what the sentence as a whole means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is ill-formed (what a nice word! :) ) language. Only a noun or an adjective can come after *become*—because the meaning of this word is about *coming to **be*** a certain way. So, you should treat "become" functionally in the same way as you treat the verb "to be" in its simplest sense of, well, being *something* (the verb "to be" is usually followed by a noun or adjective). For example, one can "become worried" ("worried" is an adjective)—because you can say, "I am worried",—but **not** "become to worry" or "become to not worry". Technically speaking, one *could* say "I am not to worry", but here, the verb "to be" becomes a modal verb—this basically says, "I should not worry"; that is why I'm saying you could find equivalency only to the *simplest sense* of "being" in the verb "to be."

To address your specific sentence, the correct way to say it would be,

> I'll definitely try it when I **stop worrying** about that.

If you need a sense that is not negative (i. e. you start to do something, not start to NOT do something, which can be transformed into "stop doing something"), you can say,

> **Once I have tried** to do it my way, I will also try the method that you are suggesting.

This construction with "once + Present Perfect" can also be applied to your specific phrase,

> I'll definitely try it **once I've stopped** worrying about that.

P. S. And yes, googling a phrase in quotation marks is often a good first step for determining whether native speakers use this phrase at all.